# Proof that three element vector space cannot be constructed over $\mathbb Z_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to show that a vector space $V$ with three elements cannot be constructed over the field $\mathbb{Z}_5$. The elements of $V$ can be shown to be $\{0,1,1^{-1}\}$. I don't think the vector space is closed under scalar multiplication, but how do I show this? As far as I know, we could define an operator $\cdot$ such that $\alpha \cdot 1 = \beta \cdot 1$ for $1 \in V$ and $\alpha, \beta \in V$. I need to prove this result using only the definitions of a vector space and of a field.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: A $k-$dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ has $5^k$ elements.

Comment: Yes, but I've yet to show this. I'm looking for a proof based only on the definitions of a vector space and a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X\ne0$ be an element of the space.  Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_5$ with $a\ne b$.  If $aX=bX$ then $(a-b)X=0$ and multiplying both sides by $(a-b)^{-1}$ gives $X=0$ contrary to assumption.

Thus, $0, X, 2X, 3X, 4X$ are all distinct.